# Append form-data with Blob, Buffer, BinaryString (Back-end NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, request, buffer, multipartform-data, form-data

Is there any way or any supported form-data package to append form-data with **Buffer, BinaryString or Blob** object and request it with content-type **multipart/form-data** through API (it's a server to server request, not from client). I already know it can be append with StreamObject, File Object but when I tried with BinaryString or Blob with **form-data npm package**, it blow an error. Suppose the Blob, Buffer I get from a remote resource, or reading a local file

For example:

```
import FormData from 'form-data';

const form = new FormData();
form.append('files[]', buffer or blob);
// buffer is retrieved as result from fs.readFile
// Then request this form to an API, it's failed
```